(FIXED, comments) Inverse Trigonometric Functions Return Incorrect Degree Values in Kotlin Calculator
1) Incorrect Outputs for Degree Mode:

asin(0.5) should return30 degrees, but it currently returns 0.5000063464.
acos(0.5) should return 60 degrees, but it currently returns 89.499993654.
atan(1) should return 45 degrees, but it currently returns 0.9998984794.

2) Validation Limits Not Applying Correctly in Degree Mode:

The input validation (validateInverseTrigArgument) is only checking that arguments are within the range [-1, 1], which is appropriate for radians but does not apply to degrees.

This is the code that is a part of Evaluator class:
    fun setRadianMode(isRadian: Boolean) {
        isRadianMode = isRadian
    }

    fun isInRadianMode(): Boolean = isRadianMode

    // Validate arguments for inverse trig functions
    private fun validateInverseTrigArgument(func: String, argument: String): Boolean {
        return try {
            val value = symbols.eval(argument)
            when (func) {
                "asin", "acos" -> value in -1.0..1.0
                else -> true
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false  // If evaluation fails, consider it invalid
        }
    }

    private fun convertTrigFunctions(expression: String): String {
        val trigFunctions = listOf("sin", "cos", "tan", "cot")
        val inverseTrigFunctions = listOf("asin", "acos", "atan", "acot")
        var modifiedExpression = expression

        // First handle regular trig functions
        for (func in trigFunctions) {
            val regex = "$func\\(".toRegex()
            val matches = regex.findAll(modifiedExpression)

            for (match in matches.toList().reversed()) {
                val startIndex = match.range.last + 1
                val endIndex = try {
                    findMatchingParenthesis(modifiedExpression, startIndex)
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    // If no closing parenthesis, treat end of expression as the closing point
                    modifiedExpression.length
                }

                val argument = modifiedExpression.substring(startIndex, endIndex)

                val convertedArgument = if (!isRadianMode) {
                    "$func($argument * $PI / 180)"
                } else {
                    "$func($argument)"
                }

                modifiedExpression = modifiedExpression.replaceRange(match.range.first, endIndex, convertedArgument)
            }
        }

        // Then handle inverse trig functions separately
        for (func in inverseTrigFunctions) {
            val regex = "$func\\(".toRegex()
            val matches = regex.findAll(modifiedExpression)

            for (match in matches.toList().reversed()) {
                val startIndex = match.range.last + 1
                val endIndex = try {
                    findMatchingParenthesis(modifiedExpression, startIndex)
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    modifiedExpression.length
                }

                val argument = modifiedExpression.substring(startIndex, endIndex)

                // Convert output of inverse trig function to degrees if in degree mode
                val convertedArgument = if (!isRadianMode) {
                    "$func($argument) * 180 / $PI"
                } else {
                    "$func($argument)"
                }

                modifiedExpression = modifiedExpression.replaceRange(match.range.first, endIndex, convertedArgument)
            }
        }

        return modifiedExpression
    }

I'm using Javia Arity / Arithmetic for my expression evaluation:
https://github.com/preda/arithmetic
I tried it with java math library but no luck
private fun evaluateInverseTrigFunction(func: String, argument: Double): Double {
    val result = when (func) {
        "asin" -> Math.asin(argument)
        "acos" -> Math.acos(argument)
        "atan" -> Math.atan(argument)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid function: $func")
    }

    // Convert to degrees if not in radian mode
    return if (!isRadianMode) result * 180 / Math.PI else result
}

private fun convertTrigFunctions(expression: String): String {
    val trigFunctions = listOf("sin", "cos", "tan", "cot")
    val inverseTrigFunctions = listOf("asin", "acos", "atan", "acot")
    var modifiedExpression = expression

    // Handle regular trig functions as before
    for (func in trigFunctions) {
        val regex = "$func\\(".toRegex()
        val matches = regex.findAll(modifiedExpression)

        for (match in matches.toList().reversed()) {
            val startIndex = match.range.last + 1
            val endIndex = try {
                findMatchingParenthesis(modifiedExpression, startIndex)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                modifiedExpression.length
            }

            val argument = modifiedExpression.substring(startIndex, endIndex)

            val convertedArgument = if (!isRadianMode) {
                "$func($argument * $PI / 180)"
            } else {
                "$func($argument)"
            }

            modifiedExpression = modifiedExpression.replaceRange(match.range.first, endIndex, convertedArgument)
        }
    }

    // Handle inverse trig functions
    for (func in inverseTrigFunctions) {
        val regex = "$func\\(([^)]+)\\)".toRegex() // Match function argument inside parentheses
        val matches = regex.findAll(modifiedExpression)

        for (match in matches.toList().reversed()) {
            val argumentStr = match.groupValues[1]

            // Evaluate the argument expression as a Double
            val argument = symbols.eval(argumentStr)

            // Get result from evaluateInverseTrigFunction
            val result = evaluateInverseTrigFunction(func, argument)

            // Replace original function call with the computed result
            modifiedExpression = modifiedExpression.replaceRange(match.range, result.toString())
        }
    }

    return modifiedExpression
}

Inverse Trig Functions: When convertTrigFunctions detects an inverse trig function (e.g., asin, acos, atan):

It extracts the argument and evaluates it as a Double.
It calls evaluateInverseTrigFunction, which computes the result and applies degree conversion if isRadianMode is false.
It replaces the original function call in the expression with the computed result.

UNIT Test case results:
    fun testAsinInDegreeMode() {
        println("Test asin function in degree mode:")
        evaluator.setRadianMode(false)
        val result = evaluator.evaluate("asin(0.5)")
        assertEquals("30", result) // asin(0.5) in degrees is 30
    }

Test asin function in degree mode: 
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :30 
Actual   :0.5000063464
Test acos function in degree mode: 
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :60 
Actual   :89.499993654
Test atan function in degree mode: 
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :45 
Actual   :0.9998984794
    fun testInvalidAsinArgument() {
        println("Test invalid argument for asin in degree mode (greater than 1):")
        evaluator.setRadianMode(false)
        val result = evaluator.evaluate("asin(2.0)")
        assertEquals("Error: Unable to show the result", result)
    }

Test invalid argument for asin in degree mode (greater than 1): 
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Error: Unable to show the result 
Actual   :2.0004063794
Test invalid argument for acos in degree mode (greater than 1): 
org.junit.ComparisonFailure:  
Expected :Error: Unable to show the result 
Actual   :87.999593621 

Have you written a more focused test case, perhaps as both a unit test (JVM) and an instrumented test (Android), to demonstrate your claims? Just test the inverse trig functions directly, avoiding your convoluted expression parsing logic. If those tests fail, edit your question and post those tests. If those tests succeed, then perhaps the problem lies somewhere other than where you think it does.

It is extremely unlikely that gross errors like this exist in any of the common trig functions or their inverses in any well used environment. The worst you are likely to see in modern implementations is that something is not quite correctly rounded. Worst I can recall is some math libraries cbrt is only good to ~15 digits out of 16. I suggest you look for errors in your convoluted  code using a debugger before you accuse the libraries of being defective. BTW An MRE needs to be self contained and much simpler than the tangle of code that you have posted above. keyword is Minimum

The results you displayed for 0.55 correspond to the following: asin(0.55 * PI / 180) * 180 / PI = 0.55, acos(0.55 * PI / 180) * 180 / PI = 89.44499, atan(0.55 * PI / 180) * 180 / PI = 0.54998.  I haven't run the code, but the cause is probably the fact that the expression "asin(0.55)" first matches the regex for sin (in the first for, for direct functions) which results in replacing it with "a" + "$func($argument * $PI / 180)", i.e., "asin(0.55 * 3.1415... / 180)".

@CommonsWare I updated the post with test cases, they confirm the issues

@kikon Let's use asin(0.5) for example. So I did this: $func($argument) * 180 / $PI, and that is supposed to be asin(0.5)×180 / PI​, yet it still isn't correct and gives me the same result even though mathematically it should correctly return 30

I FOUND THE FIX:
All I did was add to the regex \b val regex = "\\b$func\\(".toRegex()

"I updated the post with test cases" -- FWIW, they were not the test cases that I suggested. I recommended writing test cases that "test the inverse trig functions directly, avoiding your convoluted expression parsing logic".
